# What happens when destroying something that gives flash to a spell on the stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say Player 1 has something like [Shimmer Myr](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shimmer%20Myr) that reads:

> You may cast artifact cards as though they had flash.

Then when that player tries to cast an artifact as an instant, Player 2 places something like [Naturalize](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394634) on the stack to destroy target artifact (the Shimmer Myr). What happens to the artifact being cast?  What about the mana used to cast it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Player 2 can't really stop player 1 from casting an artifact as if it had flash, outside of destroying Shimmer Myr while player 1 is tapped out.

At any given time, one player has priority. If player 2 has priority first and casts Naturalize, player 1 can respond by casting an artifact. If player 1 has priority, they can cast an artifact. Once they do so, it's on the stack and it doesn't matter if player 2 casts Naturalize; the artifact has already been cast and will eventually resolve unless it's countered.

That is, Shimmer Myr's ability only matters while they're *casting* the artifact. (Same goes for flash.) You check whether you're allowed to cast a spell as part of casting it, not later, and timing restrictions are part of that.